# Remove all alphabetical letters using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this code and wanted to add some code that would remove all letters of the alphabet. Working range is `E2:E200`.

For example, `33 CONTIN, BOOST, 65NA` and they would show `33,(blank),65`.

I have tried several codes from the web but none seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried and what happened?  This is a frequently asked question and I'm surprised you haven't found a useful solution.

Comment: I cant find the exact codes but they just remove what I requested. The other kept kicking out an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Expressions. This is VBScript (which works in VBA) but uses the wsh object. You need to use Excel orwhatever to host it. ObjArgsare command line parameters - *filename, search string, replace string*.

```
Elseif objArgs.count = 3 then
        Set srcfile = fso.GetFile(objArgs(0))
        ReportErrors "srcFile"
        If err.number = 0 then Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)
        If err.number <> 0 then
            wscript.echo err.description & " " & srcFile.path, 48, "Serenity's Search" 
            err.clear
        else
            ReportErrors "TS" & "     " & srcFile.path
            Src=ts.readall
            If err.number = 62 then
                err.clear
            else
                ReportErrors "ReadTS" & "     " & srcFile.path
                regEx.Pattern = objArgs(1) 
                regEx.IgnoreCase = True
                regEx.Global = True
                NewSrc= regEx.Replace(Src, objArgs(2)) 
                If NewSrc<>Src then
                    wscript.echo "Replacement made in " & srcfile.path, 64, "Serenity's Search" 
                    TS.close
                    Set TS = srcFile.OpenAsTextStream(2, 0)
                    ts.write newsrc
                    ReportErrors "Writing file"
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ReportErrors "Check OK" & "     " & srcFile.path


Else
```

```
Special characters and sequences are used in writing patterns for regular expressions. The following table describes and gives an example of the characters and sequences that can be used.

Character  Description  
\ 
 Marks the next character as either a special character or a literal. For example, "n" matches the character "n". "\n" matches a newline character. The sequence "\\" matches "\" and "\(" matches "(".

^ 
 Matches the beginning of input.

$ 
 Matches the end of input.

* 
 Matches the preceding character zero or more times. For example, "zo*" matches either "z" or "zoo".

+ 
 Matches the preceding character one or more times. For example, "zo+" matches "zoo" but not "z".

? 
 Matches the preceding character zero or one time. For example, "a?ve?" matches the "ve" in "never". 

.
 Matches any single character except a newline character. 

(pattern)
 Matches pattern and remembers the match. The matched substring can be retrieved from the resulting Matches collection, using Item [0]...[n]. To match parentheses characters ( ), use "\(" or "\)".

x|y
 Matches either x or y. For example, "z|wood" matches "z" or "wood". "(z|w)oo" matches "zoo" or "wood". 

{n}
 n is a nonnegative integer. Matches exactly n times. For example, "o{2}" does not match the "o" in "Bob," but matches the first two o's in "foooood".

{n,} 
 n is a nonnegative integer. Matches at least n times. For example, "o{2,}" does not match the "o" in "Bob" and matches all the o's in "foooood." "o{1,}" is equivalent to "o+". "o{0,}" is equivalent to "o*".

{ n , m } 
 m and n are nonnegative integers. Matches at least n and at most m times. For example, "o{1,3}" matches the first three o's in "fooooood." "o{0,1}" is equivalent to "o?".

[ xyz ] 
 A character set. Matches any one of the enclosed characters. For example, "[abc]" matches the "a" in "plain". 

[^ xyz ] 
 A negative character set. Matches any character not enclosed. For example, "[^abc]" matches the "p" in "plain". 

[ a-z ] 
 A range of characters. Matches any character in the specified range. For example, "[a-z]" matches any lowercase alphabetic character in the range "a" through "z". 

[^ m-z ] 
 A negative range characters. Matches any character not in the specified range. For example, "[m-z]" matches any character not in the range "m" through "z". 

\b 
 Matches a word boundary, that is, the position between a word and a space. For example, "er\b" matches the "er" in "never" but not the "er" in "verb". 

\B 
 Matches a non-word boundary. "ea*r\B" matches the "ear" in "never early". 

\d 
 Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9]. 

\D 
 Matches a non-digit character. Equivalent to [^0-9]. 

\f 
 Matches a form-feed character. 

\n 
 Matches a newline character. 

\r 
 Matches a carriage return character. 

\s 
 Matches any white space including space, tab, form-feed, etc. Equivalent to "[ \f\n\r\t\v]".

\S 
 Matches any nonwhite space character. Equivalent to "[^ \f\n\r\t\v]". 

\t 
 Matches a tab character. 

\v 
 Matches a vertical tab character. 

\w 
 Matches any word character including underscore. Equivalent to "[A-Za-z0-9_]". 

\W 
 Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to "[^A-Za-z0-9_]". 

\num 
 Matches num, where num is a positive integer. A reference back to remembered matches. For example, "(.)\1" matches two consecutive identical characters. 

\ n 
 Matches n, where n is an octal escape value. Octal escape values must be 1, 2, or 3 digits long. For example, "\11" and "\011" both match a tab character. "\0011" is the equivalent of "\001" & "1". Octal escape values must not exceed 256. If they do, only the first two digits comprise the expression. Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions.

\xn
 Matches n, where n is a hexadecimal escape value. Hexadecimal escape values must be exactly two digits long. For example, "\x41" matches "A". "\x041" is equivalent to "\x04" & "1". Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions.


Remarks
The following code illustrates the use of the Pattern property. 

  Copy Code 
Function RegExpTest(patrn, strng)

   Dim regEx, Match, Matches   ' Create variable.

   Set regEx = New RegExp   ' Create a regular expression.

   regEx.Pattern = patrn   ' Set pattern.

   regEx.IgnoreCase = True   ' Set case insensitivity.

   regEx.Global = True   ' Set global applicability.

   Set Matches = regEx.Execute(strng)   ' Execute search.

   For Each Match in Matches   ' Iterate Matches collection.

      RetStr = RetStr & "Match found at position "

      RetStr = RetStr & Match.FirstIndex & ". Match Value is '"

      RetStr = RetStr & Match.Value & "'." & vbCRLF

   Next

   RegExpTest = RetStr

End Function

MsgBox(RegExpTest("is.", "IS1 is2 IS3 is4"))
```

Comment: Will this working with in a set range? Sorry my skills with VBA is NOOB.

Comment: It works on a string. SO has specific forums on RegExp search strings. But something like [^a-zA-Z] and replace with nothing will likely remove all letters. If you have Word it also has RegExp. They call it wildcards in the replace dialog. If doing it once use word, takes 3 seconds.